# PDF glyph widths for composite (Type0) fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts

In what unit/space are CIDfont widths defined?
I am trying to get device space coordinates for glyphs in a document (or, equivalently in my case, in default user space), but I'm having trouble with glyph displacement for composite fonts.

The ISO spec (8.7.1 on CIDFonts) says that DW is defined in user units.
This seems like a weird a choice, given than other font types (except Type3) have widths defined in glyph space, but it would make sense then that the widths in W are also defined in user units.

This doesn't appear to be the case though. When calculating glyph displacements (as described in 9.4.4 Text Space Details), multiplying the widths with the inverse text matrix, to convert them to text space, does not appear to give me the right results. The document I'm working on uses default user space (does not define a CTM or set the UserUnit), so by my understanding, that should have worked.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ISO spec (8.7.1 on CIDFonts) says that DW is defined in user units.

I assume you found that "user units" mentioning in ISO 32000-1, **section 9.7.4.1** (subsection "General" of section "CIDFonts"):

> **DW**
>   integer
>   *(Optional)* The default width for glyphs in the CIDFont (see 9.7.4.3, "Glyph Metrics in CIDFonts"). Default value: 1000 (defined in user units).
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 117 – Entries in a CIDFont dictionary)*

Indeed, the *"(defined in user units)"* here is quite misleading, so it has been removed in ISO 32000-2 where the corresponding entry only says

> **DW**
>   number
>   *(Optional)* The default width for glyphs in the CIDFont (see 9.7.4.3, "Glyph metrics in CIDFonts"). Default value: 1000.
>
> *(ISO 32000-2, Table 115 — Entries in a CIDFont dictionary)*

It also doesn't make any sense to assume font displacement numbers to be given in user space units as the displacement must respect current states like the text matrix, the horizontal scaling, and the font size, and therefore, cannot be a fixed dimension in user space.

Instead we're actually in just the same situation with CID fonts as with other fonts, the displacements are given in glyph space and are transformed to text space as defined in section 8.3.2.4 ("Other Coordinate Spaces") of both ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2:

> Character glyphs in a font shall be defined in *glyph space* (see 9.2.4, "Glyph Positioning and Metrics"). The transformation from glyph space to text space shall be defined by the *font matrix*. For most types of fonts, this matrix shall be predefined to map 1000 units of glyph space to 1 unit of text space; for Type 3 fonts, the font matrix shall be given explicitly in the font dictionary (see 9.6.5, "Type 3 Fonts").

Thus, the default value 1000 of the default CIDFont glyph width **DW** allows for a square 1×1 text space area, and a squarish area indeed is what many CJK glyphs can properly be drawn in, making this default value sensible.

Comment: That's exactly it. I'm sitting here with 32000-1. I thought it was strange to use user units here.